# MySQL Query Fails

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I am trying to write a query that calculates SUMS of a row and total entries based on todays date. The date field in my database is in 03/14/2012 2:03:19 format. The query is ignoring the date and returning the SUM of all entries in the database. Here is my query:

```
$string = "
  SELECT SUM(totalcollected)
  FROM accounting
  WHERE agent = '$agentid'
    AND DATE(date) = DATE(NOW())
    AND amount1type = 'Cash'
     OR amount2type = 'Cash'
";
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: "*calculates SUMS of a row*"...???

Comment: Please consider using placeholders rather than interpolated strings to construct queries.  Separately, `CURRENT_DATE` says the same thing as `DATE(NOW())`, but a bit more directly.

Comment: Plus using a function in where clause (`DATE(date)`) is a performance killer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `AND` resolves *before* `OR`, but you can avoid the `OR` entirely with this cool trick:

```
SELECT SUM(totalcollected)
FROM accounting
WHERE agent = '$agentid'
AND DATE(date) = DATE(NOW())
AND 'Cash' IN (amount1type, amount2type)
```

Comment: +1 Nice idea with the `IN (col1, col2)`! I haven't seen that done before

Comment: @Bohemian Does the date formatting in my current date entries matter when doing a DATE(NOW()) query? Your query is still not calculating my totalcollected row and I feel it has to do with the date.

Comment: This trick requires a composite index on `(amount1type, amount2type)`; otherwise it is a performance killer.

Comment: @SalmanA Care to expand on that?  How would using `in` be any less efficient than using `or`?

Comment: Create a table with a column or two plus two columns for this particular test. Add indexes to these two columns. Fill with random data (few thousand rows) Run `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM t WHERE a = 'foo' and b = 'foo'` vs `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM t WHERE 'foo' IN (a, b)`. MySQL seems to evaluate (a, b) FOR EACH ROW in the latter case.

Comment: @SalmanA You are comparing **AND**, not **OR**. Try changing it to `a = 'foo' OR b = 'foo'` - it should give the same performance as my trick.

Comment: @Bohemian: I used `EXPLAIN SELECT` command against both (and/or vs in) queries before posting. AND/OR queries were able to use index, IN did not.

Comment: @Everyone, just to answer my own question from above, the date has to be formatted like 2012-03-16 for the sql to pick it up.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [MySQL Operator Precedence chart](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operator-precedence.html). You'll notice that `AND` has a higher priority compared to `OR` so your query becomes something like:

```
SELECT SUM(totalcollected)
FROM accounting
WHERE
(
    agent = '$agentid' AND
    DATE(DATE) = DATE(NOW()) AND
    amount1type = 'Cash' 
)
OR
(
    amount2type = 'Cash'
)
```

Notice that date is taken into account when (i) agent = $agent (ii) amount1type = cash; but rows that have amount2type = cash will always be returned regardless of date. You should add the brackets to tell MySQL exactly how the where clause should be processed:

```
SELECT SUM(totalcollected)
FROM accounting
WHERE
agent = '$agentid' AND
DATE(DATE) = DATE(NOW()) AND
(
    amount1type = 'Cash' OR amount2type = 'Cash'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you're missing some parens in your `where` clause...

The final condition, `or amount2type = 'cash'` is allowing every other condition to be false.  You should change this to be grouped with the check against `amount1type`:

```
SELECT SUM(amount1), SUM(amount2), SUM(monpay), SUM(totalcollected) 
FROM accounting 
WHERE
    agent = '$agentid' 
    AND DATE(date) = DATE(NOW()) 
    AND (amount1type = 'Cash' OR amount2type = 'Cash')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need parenthesis to denote to the database what you're actually trying to do.  Better formatting will make it clearer

```
SELECT SUM(totalcollected)
FROM accounting
WHERE agent = '$agentid'
    AND  DATE(date) = DATE(NOW())
    AND amount1type = 'Cash'
    OR amount2type = 'Cash'
```

versus

```
SELECT SUM(totalcollected)
FROM accounting
WHERE agent = '$agentid'
    AND  DATE(date) = DATE(NOW())
    AND (amount1type = 'Cash' OR amount2type = 'Cash')
```